# clicking the radio button should position the top of the page automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

There is some list of about 100 rows in a page with radio button for each row with same class name

```
<input type="radio" name="onward" class="onward" value="1">
```

Clicking this radio button should move to the top of the page, i tried by using below example.

```
$(".onward").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({'top': '-=30px'},'slow');
});
```

Can any one help with this !!!!!

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, if you want the page to scroll to the top, when you click the radio button?

Comment: good question, I presumed he wanted to move the button to top of the page, but your comprehension of the question seems more to the point.

Comment: I dont want button to move to top of the page, i want like clicking the radio button should scroll the page to the top

Comment: so it's the B option in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is not perfectly clear, there are 2 possibilities:

A. You are trying to make your button move to the top of the list when clicked

Your button needs `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` positioning for your code to work. 
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76vv39dz/1/

B. You want the page to scroll to top when you click a button

Your should add an id on your list container and your button should work as an anchor to it (`#container_id`)

Comment: $(this).animate({'top': '-=30px';position:absolute;},'slow'); but no use